# Reactjs how to use useEffect to handle many changes to useState

Tags: reactjs, use-effect, use-state, react-functional-component

I have numerous `useState`s in my app. I am using `useEffect` to dispatch an action to my reducer.  Instead of using a single `useEffect` for each change to `useState`, I would like to, for efficiency and readability sake, put all the state changes in a single `useEffect`. It does not seems to work as I invisioned.  What is the correct syntax to make it functional

```
const [nameFirst, setNameFirst] = useState('');
const [nameLast, setNameLast] = useState('');
const [nameEmail, setNameEmail] = useState('');
const [namePhone, setNamePhone] = useState('');

useEffect(() => {
    if (nameFirst) {
        dispatch({ type: "NAME_FIRST", nameFirst: nameFirst });
    } else if (nameLast) {
        dispatch({ type: "NAME_LAST", nameLast: nameLast });
    } else if (nameEmail) {
        dispatch({type: "NAME_EMAIL", nameEmail: nameEmail});
    } else if (namePhone) {
        dispatch({type: "NAME_PHONE", namePhone: namePhone});
    }
}, [nameFirst, nameLast, nameEmail, namePhone]);
```

What I would like to avoid is something like...

```
useEffect(() => {
        dispatch({ type: "NAME_FIRST", nameFirst: nameFirst });
}, [nameFirst]);

useEffect(() => {
        dispatch({ type: "NAME_LAST", nameLast: nameLast });
}, [nameLast]);

useEffect(() => {
        dispatch({type: "NAME_EMAIL", nameEmail: nameEmail});
}, [nameEmail]);

useEffect(() => {
    dispatch({type: "NAME_PHONE", namePhone: namePhone});
}, [namePhone]);
```

As it doesn't seem very DRY

Comment: I actually prefer the 2nd approach; it's easier to read what each `useEffect` should do

Comment: Did you consider to use the redux hook `useSelector` instead of useState?

Comment: @LuisFilipe I did not consider the useSelector hook. I am using the contextAPI, and not redux, if that changes your comment

Comment: so, where is `dispatch` coming from? it's contextApi and not redux?

Comment: @LuisFilipe correct, from context api `const dispatch = useContext(DispatchContext);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you want to fire useEffect if one of the effect's dependancy is changed. not others. the simplest approach is use multiple useEffects. but the `if` & `else if` is incorrect & will not work.


I think you want this & actually the correct question is:

`React useEffect Fire Hook when only one of the effect's deps changes, but not the others`

some solutions:

- [React useEffect Hook when only one of the effect's deps changes, but not the others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55724642/react-useeffect-hook-when-only-one-of-the-effects-deps-changes-but-not-the-oth)

one solution is compare prevState with nextState and if there is a change, fire that!

- [How to compare oldValues and newValues on React Hooks useEffect?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53446665/9671890)

Answer (score 1):

The first approach uses `else if` so it means you only update one of them; maybe you wish to update more than one?

Nevertheless, I actually prefer the 2nd approach; it's easier to read what each useEffect should do

Finally, have you considered using redux hook `useSelector` instead of `useState`?
Unless you are doing something extra when updating the state `useSelector` should be the best option for you

Answer (score 0):

How about this code?

```js
const [data, setData] = useState({
    nameFirst: "",
    nameLast: "",
    nameEmail: "",
    namePhone: "",
});

useEffect(() => {
    setData(() => {
      data.nameFirst && dispatch({ type: "NAME_FIRST", nameFirst: nameFirst });
      data.nameLast && dispatch({ type: "NAME_LAST", nameLast: nameLast });
      data.nameEmail && dispatch({type: "NAME_EMAIL", nameEmail: nameEmail};
      data.namePhone && dispatch({type: "NAME_PHONE", namePhone: namePhone});
      return data;
    })
}, [data]);
```